# How can I know which operation must be used in the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: $100$ cows can graze a field completely in $15$ days, while $60$ cows can do it in $30$ days. How many cows are needed to do it in $10$ days?

Solution: Let $x =$ amount of grass $1$ cow can graze in $1$ day

Let $y =$ growth rate of grass in $1$ day

Let $z =$ original amount of grass in the field

"$100$ cows can graze entire field in $15$ days" implies

$15 \cdot 100 \cdot x = z + 15 \cdot y$

"$60$ cows can graze entire field in $30$ days" implies

$30 \cdot 60 \cdot x = z + 30 \cdot y$

(That is, the amount of grass eaten by the cows = the total original grass plus the amount of grass growth.)

So we have a system of equations.

$1500x = z + 15y$

$1800x = z + 30y$

Use subtraction to conclude $300x = 15y$, which means $20x = y$.

Substitute $20x$ for $y$ in the first equation.

$1500x = z + 15(20x)$

$1500x = z + 300x$

$1200x = z$

Now we have expressions for $y$ and for $z$ in terms of $x$.

Let's write out the question. How many cows $m$ are needed to graze the entire field in $10$ days?

$10 \cdot m \cdot x = z + 10 \cdot y$

Substitute in the values $y = 20x$ and $z = 1200x$.

$10 \cdot m \cdot x = 1200 x + 10 \cdot 20x$

$10x \cdot m = 1200x + 200x$

$10x \cdot m = 1400x$

Solve for $m$.

$m = \frac{1400x}{10x}$

$m = 140$

So, $140$ cows are needed to graze the field in $10$ days.

I am referring to this equation:

> $15 \cdot 100 \cdot x = z + 15 \cdot y$

Here before "equal to", multiplication is used and after "equal to" addition and "multiplication" operation is used. I want to know which exact operation must be used.

Why $15 \cdot 100 \cdot x = z + 15 \cdot y$? Why not $15 + 100 + x = z \cdot 15 + y$?

Comment: `I want to know which exact operation must be used.` Well, you couldn't *add* cows and days, could you. But that's the wrong way to go about it. The operations you use *must* reflect the reality that the equation is trying to describe. If a cow eats $x$ grass in one day, then $100$ cows eat $100 \cdot x$ grass in one day, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The equation says that two expressions are equal.  The expressions are both calculations of the amount of grass eaten.

On the left hand side, we calculate the amount the cows can eat.  That's the number of cows, times the number of days, times the amount of grass a cow eats in a day.

On the right-hand side, we calculate how much grass is available to be eaten.  That's the amount of grass that grows in a day, times the number of days, plus the amount of grass that was originally there.

The equation says that the cows can eat all the available grass.  That's what the line "That is, the amount of grass eaten by the cows = the total original grass plus the amount of grass growth," means.  There's no magic formula for which operations to use.  You have to read the math, and think about *why* the author says this is the case.